# How to pop a message scraped from a url on the screen in linux using python

Tags: python, urllib

Hi suppose i had the following code

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://card.cricket.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/SriLanka-vs-India/scorecard/matchid-1657.cms"
html  = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = html.read()
final_string = BeautifulSoup(data)
cricinfo = final_string.findAll('span',text=True)
result = cricinfo[5].encode('utf-8')
print result
```

If we run the above code the result will be

```
Sri Lanka(SL) vs India(Ind) Live Scorecard | The Times Of India Cricket Scorecard, India in Sri Lanka, 5 ODI Series, 2012
```

But is there anyway to pop this result as message or something like sometimes we will get "Software updates are available" on the right top corner of the desktop in linux machines when we start(Just to pop the result like the above format when we run the code in python as above)

My intension is to pop the result on the screen when we run the code like sometimes if we recieved a mail we will see a pop up message like `"You have recieved a message"`

Answer (score 1):

On linux, you can try the package python-notify

Comment: :Can u please provide me an example on how to pop up a asmall message using that.

Comment: first result from googling "notification linux python": www.dscripts.net/2010/09/07/create-custom-notification-on-your-ubuntu-desktop-using-python/